# Dropbox sync not working & now won't uninstall 12.04

Tags: 12.04, sync, cloud, dropbox

After problems with syncing files I have given up on Dropbox on ubuntu.
Tried reinstalling and got:

```
Selecting previously unselected package dropbox.
dpkg: regarding .../dropbox_1.6.2_i386.deb containing dropbox:
 dropbox breaks nautilus-dropbox
  nautilus-dropbox (version 0.7.1-2) is present and installed.
dpkg: error processing /home/johnnyb/Downloads/dropbox_1.6.2_i386.deb (--install):
 installing dropbox would break nautilus-dropbox, and
 deconfiguration is not permitted (--auto-deconfigure might help)
```

I have tried uninstalling the package as per Dropbox's instructions but still get a message on login from the tray app.

I've also tried Mega's cloud service but that stopped syncing and won't load either.
Mega I can't even use the browser client in chromium or firefox.

Can anyone recommend a cloud service which works??
[image: dropbox error on login]

Edit: Then straight after clicking 'Dont ask again' I get[image: next problem]
It's rather annoying.

Comment: I would like to add this has never been a problem until recently (earlier this year). Dropbox syncing worked fine on older versions of ubuntu.

Comment: In Windows I would go to msconfig or control panel administration   - services to stop this. How can I do this on ubuntu?

Comment: Sync should work fine it is probably another reason.

Answer (score 2):

The message "Dropbox is running from an unsoported location" appears always if you installed Dropbox from any source but the official PPA. Just click on "Don't ask again" and all should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

I had many problems with Dropbox and I am running Ubuntu 12.04.5 in 64 bit version. The trick that made Dropbox work for me was to do the following procedure:

1. Go to Dropbox download page. This link:
   https://www.dropbox.com/install?os=
2. Download whatever that suits you. In my case i choose the Ubuntu 64 bit version, i.e. Ubuntu (.deb) 64 bit.
3. Use software center to open that package (.deb).
4. Push the install bottom.
5. In the setup you will be asked to restart nautilus, which is the program that is running the left bar with all the programs on your desktop. So restart nautilus and you can now run the Dropbox setup.
6. Hope that helps, otherwise tell.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you could try to type in the terminal this:

```
sudo apt-get purge dropbox
```

and then type in the terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install dropbox
```

and then type in the terminal:

```
sudo apt-get --reconfigure dropbox
```

and it might work fine this way.

Answer (score 0):

I hit the same issue on 12.04. After re-installing dropbox, it was not syncing stating that version of dropbox is outdated. The issue was resolved by following the steps listed [here](https://www.dropbox.com/install?os=lnx):

On 32-bit Ubuntu:

```
# cd ~ && wget -O - "https://www.dropbox.com/download?plat=lnx.x86" | tar xzf -
```

On 64-bit Ubuntu:

```
# cd ~ && wget -O - "https://www.dropbox.com/download?plat=lnx.x86_64" | tar xzf -
```

Next, run the Dropbox daemon from the newly created .dropbox-dist folder.

```
# ~/.dropbox-dist/dropboxd
```

With these steps, my account started getting sync-ed.
HTH.